# Error sending emails in symfony 2 [Connection refused #111]

Tags: php, email, symfony, gmail, swiftmailer

I have problems sending emails from my production server with Symfony 2 , SwiftMailer and Gmail. When I send it from my localhost server no problem but when I test in the production server (Godaddy hosting) I get this error:

Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]
500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException

I googled and tried many solutions without success. In localhost server it works with any simple configuration. This is my config.yml

## Swiftmailer Configuration

swiftmailer:

```
transport:  gmail
encryption: ssl
auth_mode:  login
host:       smtp.gmail.com
port:       587
username:   myuser
password:   mypassword
```

I put all the options for test but with email transport, username and password it works in localhost. I appreciated it any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoDaddy blocks all outgoing SMTP connections on their hosting. You will have to use their SMTP relay servers instead, or get a better host.

http://help.godaddy.com/article/955

http://www.satollo.net/godaddy-using-smtp-external-server-on-shared-hosting

Comment: Definitely you are right!  I had to use their own SMTP service to deliver mails instead of my Gmail. Thanks for the direction.